# Selenium not grabbing the selected element but the one loaded by Javascript

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using selenium to grab the href attribute of the a tag. But my code is not grabing the "/pros/52698281" as it should.

Is it because my code is wrong or because some javascript is loading dynamically another url ? Could he ?

Here is the html :

```
        <article class="bi-bloc blocs clearfix  bi-pro visited" id="bi-bloc-014805042600000000C0001" data-pjtoggleclasshisto="{&quot;idbloc&quot;: {&quot;id_bloc&quot;: &quot;014805042600000000C0001&quot;, &quot;no_sequence&quot;: &quot;&quot; }, &quot;klass&quot;:&quot;visited&quot; }">
             <div class="zone-bi">
                 <a class="visible-phone mob-zone-pro pj-lb pj-link" data-pjsearchctx-sethref="" href="/pros/52698281" data-pjstats="{&quot;idTag&quot;:&quot;MOB-ZONE-PRO&quot;,&quot;pos&quot;:54,&quot;type_bi&quot;:&quot;pro&quot;,&quot;genreBloc&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;pjscript&quot;:&quot;xt_click({},'C','{%xtn2}','LR_BI::zone_identification::info{%pjstats.type_bi}::identification_pro','A');&quot;}">
                   <span class="not-visible">
                         XXXXXXXXXXX
                   </span>
                 </a>
```

I am using this code to grab the href attribute.:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(:css, "article.bi-bloc div.zone-bi a.visible-phone")
elements.each do |e|
    p e.attribute("href")
end
```

Here is the javascript code that, I think, loads dynamically another url (the one printing in my terminal).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pj_searchctx = {
    "1989516432": {
        "form": {
            "quoiqui": "climatisation",
            "ou": "paris-75",
            "proximite": 0
        },
        "search": {
            "technicalUrl":"/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=climatisation&ou=paris-75&idOu=L07505600&page=3&contexte=BupKFuSlIjbFtxi68rty83eKL16bkxx3e0d5jKAkSaA%3D&proximite=0&quoiQuiInterprete=climatisation",
            "breadcrumb": "Retour aux résultats",
            "stats": {
                "idTag": "VERS-LR-RESULTATS"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Any idea how I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using direct children in your CSS selector, try using this instead of yours (with `>`):

```
"article.bi-bloc > div.zone-bi > a.visible-phone"
```

This matches more specifically the element your looking for.